# Reference element pointing to another reference element in C#

Tags: c#, reference

I have the following Node and Circular Linked list classes:

```
class Node
    {
        public Node next;
        public int data;
        public Node(int data, Node node)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = node;
        }
    }

class CircularLinkedList
    {
        private int cRLstLength = 0;
        private Node head, tail;
        // ... other functions on Circular Linked list
    }
```

I was trying something like:

```
CircularLinkedList cRLst = new CircularLinkedList(); 
Node headPointer = cRLst.head;
Node refToHeadPointer = headPointer;
Console.WriteLine("The data here is {0}", refToHeadPointer.data);
headPointer = headPointer.next;
Console.WriteLine("The data value is now {0}", refToHeadPointer.data);
```

I was expecting the last console output to be different then the earlier one. It turns out that even though `headPointer` is pointing to the next element, `refToHeadPointer` which is pointing to `headPointer` still points to the older reference. How is this possible? `refToHeadPointer` points to `headPointer` whose value is being changed to `headPointer.next` but `refToHeadPointer` holds the earlier reference. I used C# to write this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how reference-type variables work in C#. [Reference-type variables in C# store an address that points to an object in memory.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) This may sound like a pointer, and in a way it is, but the behavior is different from how pointers behave in other languages.

Here's what's happening in your code:

```
CircularLinkedList cRLst = new CircularLinkedList(); 

//take the address stored cRLst.head and store it in the variable headPointer 
Node headPointer = cRLst.head;

//take the address stored in headPointer and store it in the variable refToHeadPointer
Node refToHeadPointer = headPointer;

//As of now, crLst.head, headPointer and refToHeadPointer all hold the same address
//Read: they "point" to the same object in memory
Console.WriteLine("The data here is {0}", refToHeadPointer.data);

//Take the address stored in headPointer.next and store it in the variable headPointer
headPointer = headPointer.next;

//As of now, headPointer and refToHeadPointer contain addresses to different objects
//refToHeadPointer is a completely separate variable from headPointer. 
//Changing the address in headPointer doesn't change the address in refToHeadPointer
//headPointer holds an address that points to the current node (headPointer.next)
//refToHeadPointer holds an address that points to the original node (cRLst.head)
Console.WriteLine("The data value is now {0}", refToHeadPointer.data);
```